# S3 Cross region replication using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, terraform, replication

I was using Terraform to setup S3 buckets (different region) and set up replication between them.

It was working properly until I added KMS in it.

I created 2 KMS keys one for source and one for destination.

Now while applying **replication configuration**, there is an option to pass destination key for destination bucket but I am not sure how to apply key at the source.

Any help would be appreciated.

```html
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "east"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "destination-bucket" {
  bucket = ""destination-bucket"
  provider = "aws.east"
  acl    = "private"
  region   = "us-east-1"
  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }
  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        kms_master_key_id = "${var.kms_cmk_dest_arn}"
        sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "source-bucket" {
  bucket = "source-bucket"
  acl    = "private"
  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }
  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        kms_master_key_id = "${var.kms_cmk_arn}"
        sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
      }
    }
  }
  replication_configuration {
    role = "${aws_iam_role.replication.arn}"

    rules {
      status = "Enabled"
   destination {
        bucket        = "${aws_s3_bucket.source-bucket.arn}"
        storage_class = "STANDARD"
  replica_kms_key_id = "${var.kms_cmk_dest_arn}"
      }
   source_selection_criteria {
      sse_kms_encrypted_objects {
      enabled = true
   }
    }
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "replication" {
  name = "cdd-iam-role-replication"
  permissions_boundary    = "arn:aws:iam::${var.account_id}:policy/ServiceRoleBoundary"
  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "replication" {
  name = "cdd-iam-role-policy-replication"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.replication.id}"

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_s3_bucket.source-bucket.arn}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_s3_bucket.source-bucket.arn}/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:ReplicateObject",
        "s3:ReplicateDelete"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.destination-bucket.arn}/*"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to share your Terraform code as an [mcve] and show any errors you get from that setup or clearly explain why it doesn't do what you want it to do please?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR actually i was updating the question. Here in code not really sure where to provide kms_key_id  at source bucket.

Comment: That's not a complete example. Any chance you could edit your question to provide something minimally complete that people can use to understand your issue better?

Comment: Hi @ydaetskcoR updating the complete example

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using a Customer Managed Key(CMK) for S3 encryption, you need extra configuration.
AWS S3 Documentation mentions that the CMK owner must grant the source bucket owner permission to use the CMK.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication-config-for-kms-objects.html#replication-kms-cross-acct-scenario

Also, a good article to summarize the S3 cross region replication configuration:

https://medium.com/@devopslearning/100-days-of-devops-day-44-s3-cross-region-replication-crr-8c58ae8c68d4

Comment: Hi the-petrolhead, Yeah saw both articles. As i have both buckets in same account and i am using same user to create those resources S3 nd CMK's i dot think its issue with owner. I guess i have multiple CMK's in my account at source which is becoming quite confusing for terraform to choose between them. as we are not mentioning it in replication configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you've got two S3 Buckets in two different regions within the same account.

One way I've done this in the past is to plan/apply the KMS keys to both regions first.

Then on a separate plan/apply, I used Terraform's data sources:

```
data "aws_kms_key" "source_credentials_encryption_key" {
  key_id = "alias/source-encryption-key"
}
    
data "aws_kms_key" "destination_credentials_encryption_key" {
  provider = aws.usEast
  key_id   = "alias/destination-encryption-key"
}
```

And used the data source for the replication configuration like so:

```
replication_configuration {
  role = aws_iam_role.replication_role.arn
  
  rules {
    status = "Enabled"
    
    destination {
      bucket = aws_s3_bucket.source_bucket.arn
      storage_class = "STANDARD"
      replicate_kms_key_id = data.aws_kms_key.destination_bucket_encryption_key.arn
    }
    
    source_selection_criteria {
      sse_kms_encrypted_objects {
        enabled = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```